# Power Automate HTTP request to filter list by a column other than Title never halts

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

I'm using the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action in a Power Automate flow. If I set the URI to be:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('myListTitle')/items?$filter=Title eq 'Example'
```

It works as expected, finishing in under a second and returning the correct fields. However, if I set it to filter by a different column like "Descr":

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('myListTitle')/items?$filter=Descr eq 'Example Description'
```

The flow then says "1 retries occured." and never seems to end (at least, not within an hour).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something specific to my situation that could be causing me this trouble?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: What is the type of column Descr ?

Comment: If `Descr` column is of type "Multiple lines of text", it will not work as it does not support filtering. Also, you have to use the **internal name** of columns in REST queries.

Comment: @Saira Descr is a single line of text.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Descr is a single line of text. It's internal name was field_2, I changed it to that and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **internal name** of columns in SharePoint REST API queries.

So, make sure you are using correct internal name & supported column type for filter in REST API.

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)